# Bit-Field with std::byte as member type cannot be initialized

Tags: c++, bit-fields, c++20

In C++20, default member initializers for bit-fields are possible. But this feature seems impossible to use with `std::byte`.

```
struct Test {
    std::byte a : 2 = std::byte{0}; // NOK
    uint8_t   b : 2 = 0; // OK
};
```

Is this intentional or a bug in g++-10 (the version I'm using).

Comment: bit-fields are a part of C++ since times prehistoric. It's nothing C++20 specific.

Comment: Whats new in C++20 are the initializers. And that is the question.

Comment: Getting different results from clang and g++ live: https://godbolt.org/z/bwC734  might just not fully implemented yet?

Comment: @RichardCritten, can confirm your results with [wandbox](https://wandbox.org/). Compiling with clang HEAD works while gcc HEAD fails with error `error: cannot convert 'std::byte' to 'unsigned char:2' in initialization`

Answer (score 1):

Fixed in gcc-trunk (version 10.0) now.